# How to make a Query in MS-Access that returns the intersection of three other queries?

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

I have a "search" form that allows the user to input location, date, or ID. This form generates three queries, which return appropriate results, or all records if no search term was input for that category. I intended to make a fourth query that took the intersection of the first three, but have been unable to make it work. I've reviewed similar questions about using the SQL INNER JOIN function but can't make it work. SQL from each of my three queries is below. (or, if there's a better way to do this, let me know. I tried doing it all in one query and it was a mess).

Qry_ByDate:

```
SELECT tbl_AssyMoves.[Assy ID], tbl_AssyMoves.[From ICA], tbl_AssyMoves.[From Loc], tbl_AssyMoves.[To ICA], tbl_AssyMoves.[To Loc], tbl_AssyMoves.Date, tbl_AssyMoves.Comments
FROM tbl_AssyMoves
WHERE (((tbl_AssyMoves.Date) Between [Forms]![Form1]![StartDate] And [Forms]![Form1]![EndDate]))
```

Qry_ByLoc:

```
SELECT tbl_AssyMoves.[Assy ID], tbl_AssyMoves.[From ICA], tbl_AssyMoves.[From Loc], tbl_AssyMoves.[To ICA], tbl_AssyMoves.[To Loc], tbl_AssyMoves.Date, tbl_AssyMoves.Comments
FROM tbl_AssyMoves
WHERE (((tbl_AssyMoves.[From ICA]) Like Forms!Form1!Combo_ICA) And ((tbl_AssyMoves.[From Loc]) Like Forms!Form1!Txt_Loc)) Or (((tbl_AssyMoves.[To ICA]) Like Forms!Form1!Combo_ICA) And ((tbl_AssyMoves.[To Loc]) Like Forms!Form1!Txt_Loc))
```

Qry_ByID:

```
SELECT tbl_AssyMoves.[Assy ID], tbl_AssyMoves.[From ICA], tbl_AssyMoves.[From Loc], tbl_AssyMoves.[To ICA], tbl_AssyMoves.[To Loc], tbl_AssyMoves.Date, tbl_AssyMoves.Comments
FROM tbl_AssyMoves
WHERE (((tbl_AssyMoves.[Assy ID]) Like [Forms]![Form1]![txt_AssyID]))
```

Comment: Without wildcards, `LIKE` is redundant and may even hinder performance. Use `=` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The intersection of the 3 queries returns all the rows for which apply all the conditions in the WHERE clauses:

```
SELECT tbl_AssyMoves.[Assy ID], tbl_AssyMoves.[From ICA], tbl_AssyMoves.[From Loc],
tbl_AssyMoves.[To ICA], tbl_AssyMoves.[To Loc], tbl_AssyMoves.Date, tbl_AssyMoves.Comments
FROM tbl_AssyMoves 
WHERE
  (tbl_AssyMoves.Date Between [Forms]![Form1]![StartDate] And [Forms]![Form1]![EndDate])
  And
  (tbl_AssyMoves.[Assy ID]) Like [Forms]![Form1]![txt_AssyID])
  And
  (((tbl_AssyMoves.[From ICA]) Like Forms!Form1!Combo_ICA) And ((tbl_AssyMoves.[From Loc]) Like Forms!Form1!Txt_Loc)) Or (((tbl_AssyMoves.[To ICA]) Like Forms!Form1!Combo_ICA) And ((tbl_AssyMoves.[To Loc]) Like Forms!Form1!Txt_Loc))
```

Comment: I had to add "Or [item] Is Null" in there to get the query to work if the user leaves some criteria blank, but otherwise this is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a UNION statement to combine the results of the three queries. In Access, `UNION` automatically doesn't return duplicates, which is likely what you want. If you do want duplicates you can use `UNION ALL`

```
SELECT tbl_AssyMoves.[Assy ID], tbl_AssyMoves.[From ICA], tbl_AssyMoves.[From Loc], 
tbl_AssyMoves.[To ICA], tbl_AssyMoves.[To Loc], tbl_AssyMoves.Date, tbl_AssyMoves.Comments

FROM 

(SELECT tbl_AssyMoves.[Assy ID], tbl_AssyMoves.[From ICA], tbl_AssyMoves.[From Loc], 
tbl_AssyMoves.[To ICA], tbl_AssyMoves.[To Loc], tbl_AssyMoves.Date, tbl_AssyMoves.Comments 
FROM Qry_ByDate

UNION SELECT tbl_AssyMoves.[Assy ID], tbl_AssyMoves.[From ICA], tbl_AssyMoves.[From Loc], 
tbl_AssyMoves.[To ICA], tbl_AssyMoves.[To Loc], tbl_AssyMoves.Date, tbl_AssyMoves.Comments 
FROM Qry_ByLoc

UNION SELECT tbl_AssyMoves.[Assy ID], tbl_AssyMoves.[From ICA], tbl_AssyMoves.[From Loc], 
tbl_AssyMoves.[To ICA], tbl_AssyMoves.[To Loc], tbl_AssyMoves.Date, tbl_AssyMoves.Comments 
FROM Qry_ById)
```

Comment: In this case a union wouldn't work because the queries are set up so that they return everything if the user doesn't identify a specific search criteria for that query. Clumsy, but it was the only path I could identify at the time. The answer above sorted me out though.